# EncryptByPassphrase in PHP query

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, zend-framework

I'm here for your help.

I'm using framework Zend with SQL Server 2008. I want to know if it's possible to use EncryptByPassPhrase in query with php like this.

```
$db->query('INSERT INTO TABLE_861_FLUX_RH_DOSSIER_ENCOURS 
                (POSITION_EMPLOI_POSTE_RCE) 
        VALUES(EncryptByPassPhrase(N'.$pass.', N'.$this->_getParam ( 'position_emploi_poste',null ).', NULL))');
```

I have an error :

> Message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Nom de colonne non valide : 'NDRH'. It's in french. In English : Column name is not valid.

PS: `NDRH` is my password I gave to encrypt the column.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure "name" column is exist in the table in Database, can check once again :-)

Comment: Yes I'm sure :)

Comment: is POSITION_EMPLOI_POSTE_RCE is a column name ?

Comment: @GautamRai Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems to be single quote problem, try below code, 

    $param = $this->_getParam ('position_emploi_poste', null);
    $db->query('INSERT INTO TABLE_861_FLUX_RH_DOSSIER_ENCOURS 
            (POSITION_EMPLOI_POSTE_RCE) 
    VALUES(EncryptByPassPhrase(N'.$pass.', N'.$param.', NULL))');
```

Comment: Same problem again :/

Comment: @VladVorobyev  try with EncryptByPassPhrase(N'.$pass.', N'.$param)

Comment: Still the same :(